# Get playground to display all loop results

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7, swift-playground

I'm using an xcode 7 playground, and I want to know how to make the playground display all the results printed out by a loop.

for example:

[image]

This will tell me the loop ran 4 times, but it will only display the last value of the iteration. Is there a way I can make it show all values?

Comment: try clearing derivedData and Xcode caches

Comment: Open the debug area below by pressing the middle icon in the upper right corner of Xcode.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Right click on the inline quick look (the gray rounded rectangle with "4" in it). There's an option to show all the results in a list:

[image: Value History]

You can also show everything that's been printed to the console for the entire playground execution by clicking the show debug area button all the way in the bottom left corner:

[image]

Comment: Right click doesn't seem to do anything in my version

Comment: Are you using a mouse? or using ctrl-click on a trackpad?

Comment: ctrl-click on a trackpad worked for me. You can also select it with a left click (it'll highlight in blue) and then go to Editor -> Result Display Mode -> Value History in the menu bar.

Comment: There was a bug in Xcode 7 that made some kinds of right-click-esque actions not trigger the menu, so you might want to update to Xcode 7.1.

Answer (score 3):

In xcode 7, right clicking with a mouse on the display box will give you the correct dropdown menu. **However**, <kbd>Ctrl-clicking</kbd> with the track pad on a macbook will *not* give the correct dropdown menu. You have to select it under the `Editor` menu.

This bug goes away in xcode 7.1

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I attach GIF image for showing executing result of playground code.
[image: GIF Animation]

Comment: Please expand your answer. How are you getting the drop down menu?

Comment: Just right click on button which is like radio button on the left side .

Answer (score 1):

You can see the results directly on the **Debug Area**

[image]

**(or)**

click anywhere on the line where your `print` method is defined and follow the below steps

```
 1. Editor -> Show Results for Current Line Editor
 2. Editor -> Result Display Mode -> Value History
```

Vice versa, you can hide the `print` details by

```
 Editor -> Hide Results for Current Line
```

[image]