# While loop on in Swift Playground

Tags: swift, while-loop, swift-playground

I am currently doing a course for Swift.

While trying to write a simple while loop like the following:

```
var counter = 0

while counter < 10 {
   counter += 1
   print(counter)
}
```

This just returns on console 0, 0, 0, 0... non stop.
So the programs doesn't add 1 to the counter, and consequently does not stop when counter < 10.

Why does this happen? I also tried to change it with:

```
counter = counter + 1
```

but the situation does not change.
I leave a screenshot of my Playground

[Playground Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4iXb.png)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Is that your actual code?

Comment: Yes, that is the exact code retrieved from the course and from my program as well.

Comment: Is this a Playground or a command-line program? What happens if you create a new fresh command-line program in Xcode, copy/paste that code, and run it?

Comment: I've edited your question to specify that it is playgrounds-related, since as a "regular" Swift program, this is valid and works as you expect.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in a Playground either. Have you restarted Xcode, created a new Playground?

Comment: (possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293442/get-playground-to-display-all-loop-results)

Comment: Yes, I already did. And with a command-line program it works.

Comment: Perhaps a problem with the dark background – just kidding :)

Comment: I tried to change the "Theme" of Xcode, and it just works as a theme. Also, the post share by zneak is not related as it just shows the history of the program ( that in my case is 0 repeated multiple times )

Comment: If restarting Xcode hasn't fixed the issue for you, I'd try clearing the DerivedData folder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043112/1646862. It seems as if the playground was compiled before you had added `counter += 1` but not after

Comment: Thank you Hristo, this solved the issue.